# Integrate xterm.js to Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, xtermjs

I'm new to Angular.
I'm trying to use xterm.js (https://xtermjs.org/) but it display badly.
Here is the render : 
[Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVSof.png)

I created a xterm component. The xterm.component.ts file code is :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Terminal } from "xterm";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xterm',
  templateUrl: './xterm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xterm.component.css'],
})
export class XtermComponent implements OnInit {
  public term: Terminal;
  container: HTMLElement;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.term = new Terminal();
    this.container = document.getElementById('terminal');
    this.term.open(this.container);
    this.term.writeln('Welcome to xterm.js');
  }
}
```

My xterm.component.html only contains this :

```
<div id="terminal"></div>
```

I don't really know what to do more ...
Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use in template reference variable by using the hash symbol

```
<div #myTerminal></div>
```

and in component

```
@ViewChild('myTerminal') terminalDiv: ElementRef;
```

In `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.term = new Terminal();
    this.term.open(this.terminalDiv.nativeElement);
    this.term.writeln('Welcome to xterm.js');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Same display with this code... I don't really get it, i think it's a CSS problem.
My goal is to use xtermjs to execute git command in a terminal, but idk how to do so.

Comment: This is a better way of initialization, but it doesn't solve the problem. You will need to use _encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None_ anyways, like @Victor96 says.

Answer (score 6):

You must set the component encapsulation

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Encountered the same problem and found this page.
Maybe this is too late for the OP, but could be useful for others.

The styles are wrong because 1) the `xterm.css` is not loaded, and 2) the encapsulation.

My solution to 1) was to add `@import 'xterm/dist/xterm.css';` in the scss file for this component.

And 2) can be solved by setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` as [Victor96's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972660/5525103), or better setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `@import 'xterm/dist/xterm.css';` works great. I tested with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` but it didn't work. But `ViewEncapsulation.None` works ok with that import. Tested with Angular 7 (Firefox and Chrome).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I had to put terminal initialation in ngAfterViewInit. Otherwise the DOM elements are undefined.